# ubuntu terminal unstable after vmbox guest addition installed

Tags: package-management

After enabling vmbox guest additions, my ubuntu became unstable. The terminal cracks that I cannot see anything on the terminal. What do I do to resolve this?

Comment: Normally there should be absolutely no relation between the Virtual Box Guest Edition and the appearance of the terminal. However, to verify uninstall the Guest Edition and see if the terminal is back to normal.